Change the default text editor for Powershell to Notepad++
I want to use Notepad++ instead of Notepad to edit my Pod configurations in Kubernetes.
kubectl edit pods my-pod
I tried to change the EDITOR environment variable, but I am getting all kinds of errors and none of it is working.

I tried manually adding the EDITOR environment variable using the GUI.
I tried adding it via command line - [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("EDITOR", "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", "User")
I tried adding it in my Powershell profile like: $env:EDITOR = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

I tried encapsulating my command within  " or '". Nothing seems to work.
I'm getting errors like:

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

or

'"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

What is the correct syntax to do this ?
OS: Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2

Your attempts to define the env. var. look correct. How do you trigger use of this variable, and under what circumstances do you see one vs. the other error message? Both error messages come from cmd.exe and the first one suggests that the executable path was used unquoted, whereas the second one suggests that the path doesn't exist.

I tried using both the Windows Terminal and the Powershell Terminal. They both give the same errors. If you quote it with " - "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" - then it says '\"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, .... If you quote it with '" - '"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"' then it says The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.error: there was a problem with the editor "cmd /C '\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\"'"

If you don't quote it - C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe then it says 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error: there was a problem with the editor "cmd /C C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe". Nothing seems to work. I haven't done any other modifications to the Terminal. I just want the kubectl edit pods my-pod command to open Notepad++ instead of Notepad.

It looks like kubectl assumes that the executable file path specified via the EDITOR environment variable contains no spaces and that any attempt to use such paths via embedded quoting doesn't work, as this result in quoting/escaping of these quotes (strangely, seemingly using POSIX-shell syntax).
Thus, the solution should be to use the short (8.3) version of the executable path, which you can obtain as follows (should work analogously with your [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable() call):
  (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).
    GetFile('C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe').ShortPath.
    Replace('\', '/')

Note the use of .Replace('\', '/') in order to translate \ characters in the path to /, given that Unix-heritage programs such as kubectl are likely to interpret (unescaped) \ as the escape character.

However, as you state, this alone is not enough, because Notepad++ by default caches changes to files that aren't explicitly saved:

That is, if you open an existing file, make changes to it, and then close Notepad++ without first having manually saved the changes, the  window closes quietly and the pending changes are cached, without modifying the underlying file. (On  reopening Notepad++, these pending changes are shown again.)

The solution is to use the -nosession CLI option, in which case closing the window after having modified the edit buffer triggers a prompt for saving as-yet unchanged changes.
You can try to implement it as follows, which relies on kubectl supporting an $env:EDITOR value containing a partial command line rather than an executable file path only:
$env:EDITOR = 
  '{0} -nosession' -f
    (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).
      GetFile('C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe').ShortPath.
      Replace('\', '/')

The above works with git on Windows, for instance; personally, I cannot test it with kubectl.

Although this opens the pod manifest in Notepad++, on the terminal it immediately cancels the editing with Edit cancelled, no changes made.

@Subzero123, please see my update.

When I try the kubectl edit command, Notepad++ displays a warning message "Amount of files to open is too large. 212086 files are about to be opened. Are you sure to open them?"

@Subzero123: I don't have kubectl, so I cannot test the solution. I've updated the answer with a solution that replaces \ with / in the path, which is likely at least part of the puzzle. With this fix, it now works as intended for me with git on Windows. Please try it with kubectl and report back (not sure why you got the message you saw).

I tried the updated $env:EDITOR = ... command with Replace('\', '/') and I get the same issue. It opens the pod manifest in Notepad++ but immediately cancels the editing with Edit cancelled, no changes made. Windows sucks, I'll accept your answer as answered and we can move on if you don't want to debug more.

@Subzero123, while I can easily install kubectl.exe, it's not clear to me how I could test an edit subcommand without further setup. If you can tell me how to get a command working with minimal setup, I'm happy to dig deeper.
